# Error Handling that give JSON

Tags: java, spring, error-handling

I'm trying to create a simple error handling project, that will give JSON with error data after receiving an error (for example 404, 422 or 500). I work with code from [this](http://www.asyncdev.net/2011/12/spring-restful-controllers-and-error-handling/) site, but it's not working for me.

I actually have this two classes:

**BasicController** class

```
package com.mycompany.jsonerrorhandler;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


/**
 * Class to catch all exception
 */
public class BasicController 
{
    @ExceptionHandler (Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ModelAndView handleAllExceptions(Exception ex)
    {
        return new JsonError(ex.getMessage()).asModelAndView();
    }
}
```

**JsonError** class

```
package com.mycompany.jsonerrorhandler;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

/**
 * Class that defines what JSON Error looks like
 */
public class JsonError 
{
    private final String message;

    public JsonError(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ModelAndView asModelAndView()
    {
        MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        return new ModelAndView(jsonView, ImmutableMap.of("error", message));
    }
}
```

I wonder what I need to connect them and receive JSON (or maybe there is other solution for this problem).

Comment: How are you accessing the web resource?

Comment: I have a simple Web Application write in Maven that give me 404.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the like you provided, the JsonError class should contain the following:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

    public class JsonError
    {
        private final String message;

        public JsonError(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public ModelAndView asModelAndView() {
            MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
            return new ModelAndView(jsonView, ImmutableMap.of("error", message));
        }
    }
```

Comment: My mistake, I copied here twice the same code. There is correct version now.